apply shift to nodes defined in foreach loop
I would like to apply yshift effect to nodes defined with foreach loop. In below example,the output line not shift as expected:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    box/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1}
]
\def\arr{
  A/0,
  B/22mm,
  C/16mm
  }
\def\dy{4mm}
\foreach \name/\offset [count=\i from 0,evaluate=\i as \j using {int(\i-1)}] in \arr {
  \ifnum\i=0
    \node[box] (P\i) {\name};
  \else
      \node[box,right=\offset of P\j] (P\i) {\name};
  \fi
  }
\draw[-angle 90] ([yshift=\dy]P0) -- ([yshift=\dy]P2) node[pos=.5,sloped,above] {direction};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


Results:


If you specify .north, the line is shifted above the tops of the nodes.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
box/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1}
]
\def\arr{
A/0,
B/22mm,
C/16mm
}
\def\dy{4mm}
\foreach \name/\offset [count=\i from 0,evaluate=\i as \j using {int(\i-1)}] in \arr {
\ifnum\i=0
\node[box] (P\i) {\name};
\else
\node[box,right=\offset of P\j] (P\i) {\name};
\fi
}
\draw[-angle 90] ([yshift=\dy]P0.north) -- ([yshift=\dy]P2.north) node[pos=.5,sloped,above] {direction};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



but I'm not sure why the line doesn't seem to be shifted at all in the original example. shouldn't it be shifted from .center by default?

Fun fact: using any explicit position works, e.g. P0.center would do as well.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz but why?

I guess this bypasses this "calculate the point closest(?) to the other node on the edge"-thingy of tikz...I forgot the details how exactly tikz determines the start point on the edge of the node.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz oh, because it's a coordinate, you mean? rather than a node at all. that makes sense, actually, even if the results are unexpected in some other sense here ;).

yes, something like that, but I don't fully understand it either. What surprises me most is that \draw ([yshift=4cm]P0) -- ([yshift=4cm]P2); gives a sloped line.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz yes, I noticed the slope when I compiled the OP's example (but obviously less pronounced with 4mm). it's definitely strange.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Indeed, when the start coordinate is a non-coordinate node, TikZ notes down that there still might be a “move to waiting” (to the border of the node) for many of the path operations. The transformed point will be just thrown away in favor of the proper point on the border.

@Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks a lot for the explanation!

You could use transform canvas={yshift=\dy} to shift the whole line instead of just the coordinates:
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    box/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1}
]
\def\arr{
  A/0,
  B/22mm,
  C/16mm
  }
\def\dy{4mm}
\foreach \name/\offset [count=\i from 0,evaluate=\i as \j using {int(\i-1)}] in \arr {
  \ifnum\i=0
    \node[box] (P\i) {\name};
  \else
      \node[box,right=\offset of P\j] (P\i) {\name};
  \fi
  }
\draw[transform canvas={yshift=\dy},-angle 90] (P0) -- (P2) node[pos=.5,sloped,above] {direction};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


